# JavaScript Temperature Conversion Challenge Issue

Tags: javascript

First post on here as a new work in progress studying developer. :)

Over on Scrimba I got tasked with creating a simple temperature converter from F to C.

I understand their solution but can't seem to figure out why mine keeps returning as NaN. I get that it's not a number but I thought I did using parseInt().

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Working Solution by Them

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    let fahrenheitTemp = document.getElementById("temperature").value;
    
    fahrenheitTemp = parseInt(fahrenheitTemp);
    
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = (( fahrenheitTemp - 32 ) * 5/9).toFixed(2);
})
```

My Solution Issue

```
const convertBtn = document.querySelector(`#btn`);
let fahrenheitTemp = document.querySelector(`#temperature`).value;
const result = document.querySelector(`#result`);


function tempConversion() {
    fahrenheitTemp = parseInt(fahrenheitTemp);
    result.textContent = ((fahrenheitTemp - 32) * 5/9).toFixed(2);
}

convertBtn.addEventListener(`click`, tempConversion);
```

Comment: what's the original value of fahrenheitTemp before you parse it? can you add your html?

Comment: You've done well to show us minimal JS code. Even better if you could do a "Snippet" which allows you to include the corresponding HTML, so that we can see it in context and actually try it out. Have a look at the "Add snippet" button. Should be quick and encourage people to respond.

Comment: @Eureka thank you for this suggestion. Very new to this so appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in this line:

```
fahrenheitTemp = document.getElementById("temperature").value;
```

You are getting a value into a "regular" variable.
It has no "live" connection to the HTML element.
Try, instead:

```
fahrenheitTemp = document.getElementById("temperature");
```

and, in your function, instead of:

```
fahrenheitTemp = parseInt(fahrenheitTemp);
```

use:

```
fahrenheitTemp = parseInt(fahrenheitTemp.value);
```

---

Comment: If this works for you - can you select my answer, please?

Answer (score 1):

**I think this may work for you..**

```js
function FernhtToCelcs() {
  let feren = $("#temp")[0].value;
  let celcs = (( feren - 32 ) * 5/9).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("tempincec").innerHTML = celcs + ' C';
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}

button {
  background: #0095ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 7px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#tempincec {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="temp">Temprature in fahrenheit : </label>
  <input type="number" id="temp" name="temp">
  <button onclick="FernhtToCelcs()">Convert</button>
</div>
<p>Temprature in celcius : <span id="tempincec"></span></p>
```